# Checking, if String is Palindrome using substring() and charAt()

Tags: java

My code is supposed to ask a user to input a String and then check to see, if it is Palindrome using `charAt()` and `substring()` methods. I believe, I have done everything correctly but NetBeans is compiling it incorrectly.

When I run my code, NetBeans tells me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - missing return statement
    at palindrome.Palindrome.methodA(Palindrome.java:31)
    at palindrome.Palindrome.main(Palindrome.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

So, basically it says I'm missing a return statement? I do not see how that is possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys. Thanks.

```
package palindrome;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {

    /**
     * Program asks user to enter a string.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userInput; //user-inputted String
        String result;

        //set up instance of Scanner for user input
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //ask user for input
        System.out.print("Please enter a String: ");
        userInput = scan.nextLine();

        //run methodA
        result = methodA(userInput);

    }

    public static String methodA(String inString) {
        /*
         * This method checks the user-inputted String against a backward copy
         * of itself using only String and Character methods.
         */

        //next two int variables used as int pointers for first letter of String
        //and last letter of user-inputted String
        int begPoint = 0;
        int endPoint = inString.length() - 1;

        //define Strings to return to main method
        String isPal = (inString + " is a palindrome!");
        String notPal = (inString + " is not a palindrome.");

        while (begPoint < endPoint) {
            //two substrings defined to test String character for character
            String firstChar = inString.substring(begPoint, begPoint + 1);
            String lastChar = inString.substring(endPoint, endPoint + 1);

            //algorithm continues step by step with begPoint going up one and 
            //endPoint decreasing by one
            begPoint++;
            endPoint--;

            //basically here I am trying to check the characters of the user-
            //inputted Strings using the charAt methods but I'm lost when I
            //get to this point
            if (inString.charAt(begPoint) == inString.charAt(endPoint)) {
                return isPal;
            } else {
                return notPal;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After some answers -- I have now changed my while statement to this:

```
while(begPoint<endPoint) {
    //two substrings defined to test String character for character
    String firstChar = inString.substring(begPoint, begPoint + 1);
    String lastChar = inString.substring(endPoint, endPoint + 1);

    //basically here I am trying to check the characters of the user-
    //inputted Strings using the charAt methods 
    if (inString.charAt(begPoint) == inString.charAt(endPoint)) {
        return isPal;
    } else {
        return notPal;
    }

    //algorithm continues step by step with begPoint going up one and 
    //endPoint decreasing by one
    begPoint++;
    endPoint--;
}
```

However, now it is telling me that (begPoint++) is an unreachable statement.

Comment: Why exactly is it compiling wrong? Is there an compile error? If so, please include it. Is it not providing the correct output? If so, please include your inputs and outputs and the expected output.

Comment: This must be the remark of the year `but Netbeans is compiling it incorrectly`

Comment: @hsun324 I included the exception in an edit.

Comment: If `inString.length()` is 0 or 1 then `while(begPoint<endPoint)` will be immediately false. Then what should the program do?

Comment: If begPoint is greater than endPoint, the while loop will never be entered and so your method won't return. You need to add a return statement outside your while loop to indicate that that problem occurred.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I do not understand what you mean by the return statement outside of the while loop to indicate the problem occurred.

Comment: @user2803066 - if I pass in the string "a" or "" (an empty string of length 0), what happens? Run through your code by hand (IE, print it out and mark what each variable gets set to and which code gets run and which code ends up getting skipped.) I'll let you know right now - neither of your return statements will be called, and that's why it refuses to compile right now. You also have the problem the other answer (not mine) pointed out, which won't cause a compilation failure, but your code will say "abca" is a palindrome, when it's not. Again, run your code by hand.

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
if(inString.charAt(begPoint)==inString.charAt(endPoint))
{
       return isPal;
}
else
{
       return notPal;
}
```

you are basically returning in the first iteration of the loop.

If it is not a Palindrome, then it makes sense to return immediately, but other wise you need to continue through the loop.

Also the code will not compile if the `while` is not entered. maybe return `notPal`

Also (Thanks to ArtOfWarfare),  you need to move

```
//algorithm continues step by step with begPoint going up one and 
//endPoint decreasing by one
    begPoint++;
    endPoint--;
```

to the end of your while loop i.e. after you have done the `if` statement.

Comment: +1: I missed that. But even if you fix that, you'll still have the problem I mentioned.

Comment: @user2310289 so basically...I should move the code (begPoint++; endPoint--) to after the if/else statement????

Comment: @user2803066 - Yes, in addition to the other two fixes you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're moving begPoint and endPoint before checking the charAts. Move the code advancing begPoint and endPoint to after you use the method charAt.

Comment: @artofwarfare I edited my original post showing the changes you told me to make. Still getting some errors.